# Jasmine test presence of css selector

Tags: css, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

Jasmine and Karma, latest version, testing an AngularJS instance.

I tried

```
expect(element('a.topic-heading-link-10')).toBeDefined();
```

but it responds

```
expect undefined toBeDefined undefined
http://example.com/test/e2e/scenarios.js:16:7
expected undefined but was undefined
```

Not doesn't look very good. What is a better way to test the presence of a CSS selector?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `count` to ensure your "look up" found something. For instance:

```
expect(element('a.topic-heading-link-10').count()).toEqual(1);
```

If the element doesn't exists or it doesn't have that specific class, `count()` will equal 0.